# Have a .bat script recognise if i'm in cmd.exe or powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

Since the Microsoft quickaccess feature is very slow I prefer not to use it, and sometimes loading a folder takes too much time as well, I made a simple script to jump more easily among my "favorite" folders.
i.e. I open a cmd and type `gt tools g`, the **gt.bat** script will go to the folder and then open gvim in that folder.
Since I'm a freshman in shell scripting the syntax is as easy as it gets:

```
if /I "%1" == "tools" goto TOOLS
if /I "%1" == "dow"   goto DOW
:: ...a couple rows below...
:TOOLS
cd /d "G:\Shared drive\Stuff\Tools\"
goto EV2
:DOW
cd /d "C:\Users\myself\Downloads"
goto EV2
:: ... and so on for some 10 folders and again the second argument
```

I need to do `cd /d <folder>` because some folders are on a shared drive and some on C:, and on cmd it's the only way to navigate between drives.

**Problem**: if instead of cmd.exe I use PowerShell, the syntax `cd /d <folder>` is wrong. I should now use cd  regardless of where I am, and the script fails otherwise.
I guess the easiest solution is to check whether the script was launched by cmd or powershell, but I can't find a command for that.
Any suggestion? Or maybe it's better to stick to one type of shell?

Comment: If the `cd` is the only issue you're facing, you could try using `pushd` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to distinguish between CMD and Powershell only because of `cd /d driveletter:`, why don't you try:

```
if /I "%1" == "tools" goto TOOLS
if /I "%1" == "dow"   goto DOW
:: ...a couple rows below...
:TOOLS
G:
cd "\Shared drive\Stuff\Tools\"
goto EV2
:DOW
C:
cd "\Users\myself\Downloads"
goto EV2
:: ... and so on for some 10 folders and again the second argument
```